# Mount volumes with Secrets using Python Kubernetes API

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetespodoperator

I'm writing an Airflow DAG using the `KubernetesPodOperator`. A Python process running in the container must open a file with sensitive data:

```
with open('credentials/jira_credentials.json', 'r') as f:
    creds = json.load(f)
```

and a CloudStorage client must be authenticated:

```
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "credentials/cloud_storage_credentials.json"
```

According to the best security practices I don't package a container's image with sensitive data. Instead I use [Kubernetes Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/). Using [Python API for Kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python) I'm trying to mount them as a volume but with no success. The `credentials/` directory exists in the container but it's empty. What should I do to make files *jira_crendentials.json* and *cloud_storage_credentials.json* accessible in the container?

My DAG's code:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.kubernetes.secret import Secret
from airflow.kubernetes.volume import Volume
from airflow.kubernetes.volume_mount import VolumeMount
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from kubernetes.client import models as k8s

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

volume = Volume(name="volume-credentials", configs={})
volume_mnt = VolumeMount(mount_path="/credentials", name="volume-credentials", sub_path="", read_only=True)

secret_jira_user = Secret(deploy_type="volume",
                          deploy_target="/credentials",
                          secret="jira-user-secret",
                          key="jira_credentials.json")
secret_storage_credentials = Secret(deploy_type="volume",
                                    deploy_target="/credentials",
                                    secret="jira-trans-projects-cloud-storage-creds",
                                    key="cloud_storage_credentials.json")



dag = DAG(
    dag_id="jira_translations_project",
    schedule_interval="0 1 * * MON",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0),
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=default_args
)

start = DummyOperator(task_id='START', dag=dag)

passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                                image="eu.gcr.io/data-engineering/jira_downloader:v0.18",
                                cmds=["/usr/local/bin/run_process.sh"],
                                name="jira-translation-projects-01",
                                task_id="jira-translation-projects-01",
                                get_logs=True,
                                dag=dag,
                                volumes=[volume],
                                volume_mounts=[volume_mnt],
                                secrets=[
                                    secret_jira_user,
                                    secret_storage_credentials],
                                env_vars={'MIGRATION_DATETIME': '2021-01-02T03:04:05'}, 
                                )

start >> passing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/VBhojawala/airflow/blob/k8s-docs/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/operators.rst#mounting-secrets-as-volume) example, `Secret` is a special class that will handle creating volume mounts automatically. Looking at your code, seems that your own volume with mount `/credentials` is overriding `/credentials` mount created by `Secret`, and because you provide empty `configs={}`, that mount is empty as well.

Try supplying just `secrets=[secret_jira_user,secret_storage_credentials]` and removing manual `volume_mounts`.

---

- [Code that generates secret volume mounts under the hood](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/8505d2f0a4524313e3eff7a4f16b9a9439c7a79f/airflow/kubernetes/secret.py#L91-L108)